# How can I access /sdcard/ when I connect to PC (MTP)

Tags: mtp

I'm running a Nexus 5 (Android 6.0.1)

Today I have created a WhatsApp backup file and wanted to copy it to a new device. I can confirm the file existence in ES File Explorer.

[image: The backup file can be found in ES File Explorer]
<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

However, I cannot find the file when I connect my Nexus 5 with a USB (MTP).
[image: But the file is missing when I connect the device to my PC]

After further checking I found the file is stored in `/sdcard/WhatsApp`, while my PC is connecting to `/Internal Storage/WhatsApp`
[image]
<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

But I cannot find `/sdcard/` in my PC...

To make things more complicated, when I reboot the N5, the file appears again `/Internal Storage/WhatsApp/`

I've been a long time Android user since Motorola Milestone. I'm not a dev but luckily I have the experience in tackling such issue. But for a normal user without in-depth computer knowledge, this inconsistent behavior is just weird. There's a long way for Android to catch up with iOS in terms of user friendliness.

Comment: In your case `/sdcard/` (Android's way of naming it) and /Internal storage/`  (Windows way of naming it) are same directory. As for why the file appears after reboot is because of a bug in __MTP__ mode which misses to list files sometimes and a reboot solves that. [Further read 1- SDCard same as Internal Storage](http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=14196) and [Further read 2 -MTP issue](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1719628)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now I understand the issue was reported in 2012 but still not fixed in 2015. That's insane.

Comment: [Issue 195362: Android not showing files in MTP until device reboot](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195362)

Answer (score 2):

`/sdcard` and `/Internal storage` are same directory.

As for why the file does not appear instantly is because of a [bug in MTP mode](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282) as MTP cache is outdated until a phone reboot. If you do not wish to reboot the phone,

Possible [Workaround](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=27808122&postcount=2):

- **Settings** → **Application Manager** → All **Apps** *tab* → **Media Storage** → **Clear Data**
- Install [SD Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.jerickson314.sdscanner) app → *Open* App →  Click on *Start Rescan*

<sup>Tested and Works on Android 5.0 Lollipop</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can Install [Sarkie's MTPFix App](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=382820068000&name=MTPFix.apk&token=ABZ6GAeIWQjRqhy6T8Q0gAwDouXunt3orw%3A1450934899020&id=38282&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAdu755PgfwwlgkrKVlEqpSOXDIweg%3A1450934899020) for a permanent solution which fixes the issue.
This Automates the [2 step process mentioned in the other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132389/119358).

It monitors all the folders for new files and then adds them to *MediaScanner*. When Connected to a Computer, I copied a file to `/sdcard` from `/ExternalSDCard` using File Manager on phone and could see the file *instantly* show up on my Computer's Internal Storage listing.

Install the [MTPFix App](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=382820068000&name=MTPFix.apk&token=ABZ6GAeIWQjRqhy6T8Q0gAwDouXunt3orw%3A1450934899020&id=38282&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAdu755PgfwwlgkrKVlEqpSOXDIweg%3A1450934899020) and Click on *Start MTPFix Service*

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282#c68)